# I forgot to put single quotes in following query "select MONTH(2014-08-01);" It returns an answer of 6. How come?

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql

Does anyone have the definition of this function or explanation for this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because (the subtraction 2014-8-1) is 2005 and `month` from "start of time" + 2005 days is 6

```
select(dateadd(d,2005 ,'1900-01-01'))
```

1905-**06**-29 00:00:00.000

Implicit casting almost as bad as JavaScript!

Comment: "Implicit casting almost as bad as JavaScript!" Even if your answer was wrong (and it's not), That alone is worth the upvote.